# Azure SearchResult limit in content size?

Tags: .net, azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-search

I've built a small app using .NET SDK that fetches XML Documents from Blobstorage using Azure search. However, when converting the string to XML and using XPath to get certain values out of the content I noticed that in some cases the content is incomplete, last lines are missing and not valid XML.

```
var results = await indexClient.Documents.SearchAsync<SearchOrderResult>(param, parameters);
```

are there a size limit for the automapped content and if so, is there a workaround? (The example I found seem to be cut after 33109 charcters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Search [limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage#how-azure-search-indexes-blobs) how much text it extracts depending on the pricing tier: `32,000 characters for Free tier`, 64,000 for Basic, and 4 million for Standard, Standard S2 and Standard S3 tiers. A warning is included in the indexer status response for truncated documents.

So scale up your tier to higher.

And read xml content refer to this [article](http://csharp.net-informations.com/xml/how-to-read-xml.htm).